# Qt/C++ event loop exception handling

Tags: qt, exception, event-loop

I am having an application heavily based on QT and on a lot of third party libs. These happen to throw some exceptions in several cases.

In a native Qt App this causes the application to abort or terminate. Often the main data model is still intact as I am keeping it in pure Qt with no external data.

So I am thinking that I could also just recover by telling the user that there has occurred an error in this an that process and he should save now or even decide to continue working on the main model.

Currently the program just silently exits without even telling a story.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you are asking.  Somewhere you need to have code that handles the interaction between Qt and these other libraries.  Do your error handling and recovery there.  (Yes, I know it might be many, many places.)

Comment: HI Caleb, thank you for your commment,  I have tried this, but the other lib just aborts and kills the program before it reaches the exception. In the meantime I have installed an exception handler that is recovering whenever an exception is thrown. Unfortunately the third party lib seems to catch the exception before an abort immediately. The debugger only tells me about an access violation in the third party code.

Comment: @Georg, you probably figured it out by now. I'm posting for others that might have the same issue. In C++ access violation and division by 0 don't throw exceptions (at least normally). The program just terminates as soon as one of this two kinds of error happens.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes it's really hard to catch all exception. If one exception accidently slips through, the following helps a lot. Inherit from `QApplication` and override the `notify()` function in the following way

```c
bool MyApplication::notify( 
QObject * receiver, 
QEvent *  event ) 
{
    try 
    {
        return QApplication::notify(receiver, event);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        assert( !"Oops. Forgot to catch exception?" );

        // may be handle exception here ...
    }

    return false;
}
```

Then replace the `QApplication` in your `main()` function by your custom class. All `events` and `slots` are issued through this function, so that all exceptions can be caught and your application becomes stable.

Answer (score 5):

As stated in the Qt documentation [here](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/exceptionsafety.html), Qt is currently not fully exception safe.  The "Recovering from exceptions" section on that page describes the only thing which you can do in a Qt application when an exception is thrown - clean up and exit the app.

Given that you are using third party libraries which do throw exceptions, you need to catch these at the boundary between the external library and the Qt code, and handle them there - as stated in Caleb's comment.  If the error must be propagated into the Qt application, this must be done either by returning an error code (if possible), or by posting an event.

Comment: thank you for your comment, I have remimplented QApplication::notify() and catch everything there. This is pretty good as the app just does not simply exit but allows the user to save his data at least now. I have tested this by throwing exceptions std::bad_alloc and the like from my code. In addition, I am calling the third party lib's code from inside a try {} catch(...), but nothing happens, the app just crashes.